How to trace the creation of a token during Google account creation?
I am facing an issue while trying to create a Google account. During the password entry stage, the system generates a token via gstatic.com.
I debug the code, I can see the token within the scope. However, I need to understand how this token is being created. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
debug
